# dynamically extending <ul> in jquerymobile loses format

Tags: php, javascript, html, dynamic, jquery-mobile

I got an issue with jQueryMobile. I'm trying to append more `<li>` tags to a `<ul>` with a javascript function. It appends the items but doesn't get the formatting from jQueryMobile.

The html looks like

```
<input type="search" id="customerSearch" onKeyUp="listCustomers();" placeholder="Sök kund" />
<ul data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="d" id="customerList">
</ul>
```

And the javascript function listCustomers()

```
function listCustomers(){
    $("#customerList").empty();
    if($("#customerSearch").val().length > 2){
        $.getJSON("getCustomers.php", { sSearch : $("#customerSearch").val() }, function(data){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                $("#customerList").append("<li><a href='javascript: alert(\""+data[i].namn+"\");'>"+data[i].id+" - "+data[i].namn+"</a></li>"); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope anyone has some idéas how to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
var container = document.getElementById('customerList');
var new_element = document.createElement('li');
new_element.innerHTML ="<a href='javascript: alert(\""+data[i].namn+"\");'>"+data[i].id+ 
     " - "+data[i].namn+"</a>";
container.appendChild(new_element);
container .listview("refresh");
```

Comment: that didn't make any difference :( Added that in the end of my javascript function

Comment: Whith that it only appends one result and still not the right formatting.